# Using the last (engulfing) candles low as stoploss

Tags: pine-script, trading

I have a question for my pine script. 
The idea of the strategy:
- simple trend following strategy
- checking if in upward/downward trend
- when engulfing candle forms, I want to enter trade on the next candle

Question:
I want to have my stoploss at the low of that engulfing candle.
The TP should be 1.25 times the height of that (previous) engulfing candle.

I am kind of struggeling with this last part.

Can anyone help?

All the best!

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © c4ss10p314

//@version=4
strategy(title = "3emaFX", shorttitle = "3ema", overlay = true, initial_capital = 100000, process_orders_on_close = false)
price = strategy.position_avg_price

//input variables
hammerBodyHeight = input(title="Hammer Body, Max Height (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=300,confirm=false)
bullEnHeight = input(title="BullEn, Height (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=3,confirm=false)
bullEnAbove = input(title="BullEn Above (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=1,confirm=false)
bullEnBelow = input(title="BullEn, Below (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=0,confirm=false)
bearEnHeight = input(title="BearEn, Height (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=3,confirm=false)
bearEnAbove = input(title="BearEn Above (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=0,confirm=false)
bearEnBelow = input(title="BearEn, Below (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=1,confirm=false)


//Candlestick patterns
invertedHammer = (abs(close - open) / syminfo.mintick <= hammerBodyHeight) and (close > open) and ((high - close) > (close - open)) and ((open - low) <= (close - open) / 2)
hammer = (abs(close - open) / syminfo.mintick <= hammerBodyHeight) and (close > open) and ((close - open) < (open - low)) and ((high - close) <= (close - open) / 2)
bullEngulfing = ((open[1] - close[1]) / syminfo.mintick >= bullEnHeight) and (close > open) and ((close - open[1]) / syminfo.mintick >= bullEnAbove) and ((close[1] - open) / syminfo.mintick >= bullEnBelow)
bearEngulfing = ((close[1] - open[1]) / syminfo.mintick >= bearEnHeight) and (close < open) and ((open - close[1]) / syminfo.mintick >= bearEnAbove) and ((open[1] - close) / syminfo.mintick >= bearEnBelow)
ema8 = ema(close, 8)
ema13 = ema(close, 13)
ema21 = ema(close, 21)

//chart plotters
plotshape(bullEngulfing, style=shape.arrowup, location=location.abovebar, color = color.green, text='BullEng')
plotshape(invertedHammer, style=shape.flag, location=location.abovebar, color = color.green, text='Inv Hammer')
plotshape(hammer, style=shape.flag, location=location.abovebar, color = color.green, text='Hammer')
plotshape(bearEngulfing, style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.belowbar, color = color.red, text='BearEng')
plot(ema8, color = color.blue, linewidth=1)
plot(ema13, color = color.green, linewidth=1)
plot(ema21, color = color.orange, linewidth=1)


//Trade conditions
longEntry = close > ema8 and ema8 > ema13 and bullEngulfing and barstate.isconfirmed
shortEntry = close < ema8 and ema8 < ema13 and bearEngulfing
longExit = close <= ema13


//Risk management variables
// RM - inputs
// position_size = 

clockwork = barssince(valuewhen(bullEngulfing, price, 1)) + 1
EngHeight = abs(open[clockwork] - close[clockwork]) / syminfo.mintick
execProfitTarget = (price + (EngHeight * 1.25))
execStopLoss = (price - EngHeight)

//timeframe
start = timestamp(2019, 6, 3, 0, 0)
end = timestamp(2020, 6, 5 , 0, 0)

//Entry
if time >= start and time <= end
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, strategy.equity[0.01], when = longEntry)
//    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, strategy.equity[0.01], when = shortEntry)

// Exit
strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry = "Long", profit = execProfitTarget, stop = execStopLoss)
// strategy.close("Close Long", from_entry = "Long", profit = execProfitTarget, loss = execStopLoss)

// Check ob trend die letzten x Kerzen schon trend war
// Line 49: Strategy.equity - andere Lösung (Positionsgröße berechnen)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Version 1

This should get you closer to your goal:

- We use 10% of equity for position sizing.
- Entries are triggered only when we are not in a trade.
- Stop is specified as price, not ticks.
- Debugging plots are included at the end.
- Dates were changed to see more examples of trades.

```
// © c4ss10p314

//@version=4
strategy(title = "3emaFXlong", shorttitle = "3emaL", overlay=true, initial_capital = 100000, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 10)
price = close

//input variables
hammerBodyHeight = input(title="Hammer Body, Max Height (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=300,confirm=false)
bullEnHeight = input(title="BullEn, Height (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=3,confirm=false)
bullEnAbove = input(title="BullEn Above (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=1,confirm=false)
bullEnBelow = input(title="BullEn, Below (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=0,confirm=false)
inpTakeProfit = input(1.25, title = "Example-Take Profit Multiplier", minval = 0.1, maxval = 5, step = 0.1)

//Candlestick patterns
invertedHammer = (abs(close - open) / syminfo.mintick <= hammerBodyHeight) and (close > open) and ((high - close) > (close - open)) and ((open - low) <= (close - open) / 2)
bullEngulfing = ((open[1] - close[1]) / syminfo.mintick >= bullEnHeight) and (close > open) and ((close - open[1]) / syminfo.mintick >= bullEnAbove) and ((close[1] - open) / syminfo.mintick >= bullEnBelow)
ema8 = ema(close, 8)
ema13 = ema(close, 13)
ema21 = ema(close, 21)

//chart plotters
plotshape(bullEngulfing, style=shape.arrowup, location=location.abovebar, color = color.green, text='BullEng')
plotshape(invertedHammer, style=shape.flag, location=location.abovebar, color = color.green, text='Inv Hammer')

plot(ema8, color = color.blue, linewidth=1)
plot(ema13, color = color.green, linewidth=1)
plot(ema21, color = color.orange, linewidth=1)


//Trade conditions
longEntry = close > ema8 and ema8 > ema13 and bullEngulfing
longExit = close <= ema13


//Risk management variables
// RM - inputs
// position_size = 
execProfitTarget = (price * 1.05) / syminfo.mintick
execStopLoss = (price * 0.98)

//timeframe
start = timestamp(2000, 5, 27, 0, 0)
end = timestamp(2020, 6, 30 , 0, 0)

//Entry & exit
if time >= start and time <= end and longEntry and strategy.opentrades == 0
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry = "Long", profit = execProfitTarget, stop = execStopLoss)

// Debugging.
plotchar(longEntry, "longEntry", "▲", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(close > ema8, "close > ema8", "•", location.bottom, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(ema8 > ema13, "ema8 > ema13", "—", location.bottom, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(execProfitTarget, "execProfitTarget", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(execStopLoss, "execStopLoss", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(strategy.opentrades, "strategy.opentrades", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

#### Version 2

```
// © c4ss10p314

//@version=4
strategy(title = "3emaFXlong", shorttitle = "3emaL", overlay=true, initial_capital = 100000, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 10)
price = close

//input variables
hammerBodyHeight = input(title="Hammer Body, Max Height (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=300,confirm=false)
bullEnHeight = input(title="BullEn, Height (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=3,confirm=false)
bullEnAbove = input(title="BullEn Above (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=1,confirm=false)
bullEnBelow = input(title="BullEn, Below (Pips)",minval=1,maxval=100,step=1,defval=0,confirm=false)
inpTakeProfit = input(1.25, title = "Example-Take Profit Multiplier", minval = 0.1, maxval = 5, step = 0.1)

//Candlestick patterns
invertedHammer = (abs(close - open) / syminfo.mintick <= hammerBodyHeight) and (close > open) and ((high - close) > (close - open)) and ((open - low) <= (close - open) / 2)
bullEngulfing = ((open[1] - close[1]) / syminfo.mintick >= bullEnHeight) and (close > open) and ((close - open[1]) / syminfo.mintick >= bullEnAbove) and ((close[1] - open) / syminfo.mintick >= bullEnBelow)
ema8 = ema(close, 8)
ema13 = ema(close, 13)
ema21 = ema(close, 21)

//chart plotters
plotshape(bullEngulfing, style=shape.arrowup, location=location.abovebar, color = color.green, text='BullEng')
plotshape(invertedHammer, style=shape.flag, location=location.abovebar, color = color.green, text='Inv Hammer')

plot(ema8, color = color.blue, linewidth=1)
plot(ema13, color = color.green, linewidth=1)
plot(ema21, color = color.orange, linewidth=1)


//Trade conditions
longEntry = close > ema8 and ema8 > ema13 and bullEngulfing
longExit = close <= ema13


//Risk management variables
// RM - inputs
// position_size = 

//timeframe
start = timestamp(2000, 5, 27, 0, 0)
end = timestamp(2020, 6, 30 , 0, 0)

//Entry & exit
var float execProfitTarget = na
var float execProfitPrice = na
var float execStopLoss = na
if time >= start and time <= end and longEntry and strategy.opentrades == 0
    // We know that we enter here only when a bullEngulfing was encountered, 
    // which means the current OHLC prices are those of that engulfing bar.
    execProfitTarget := (abs(close - open) * 1.25) / syminfo.mintick
    execProfitPrice := close + execProfitTarget * syminfo.mintick
    execStopLoss := low
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry = "Long", profit = execProfitTarget, stop = execStopLoss)

// Plot stop and target.
inTrade = strategy.opentrades != 0
plot(inTrade ? execStopLoss : na, "Stop", color.red, 1, plot.style_circles)
plot(inTrade ? execProfitPrice : na, "Target", color.lime, 1, plot.style_circles)

// Debugging.
// plotchar(strategy.opentrades, "strategy.opentrades", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
// plotchar(inTrade, "inTrade", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
// plotchar(longEntry, "longEntry", "▲", location.top, size = size.tiny)
// plotchar(close > ema8, "close > ema8", "•", location.bottom, size = size.tiny)
// plotchar(ema8 > ema13, "ema8 > ema13", "—", location.bottom, size = size.tiny)
// plotchar(execProfitTarget, "execProfitTarget", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
// plotchar(execStopLoss, "execStopLoss", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
// plotchar(strategy.opentrades, "strategy.opentrades", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey! The code you posted is only plots for debugging.

Comment: My problem is, to measure the "pre-entry" bar and use it as stop loss or take profit..

Comment: ) The debugging plots help you visualize that the information your strategy is using corresponds to what's expected. The `execProfitTarget = (price * 1.05) / syminfo.mintick` line is the one calculating your target, which can now be reached by your strategy because I changed your stop loss value to price rather than to ticks as you had before, which caused your positions to exit prematurely, most often on the same bar. The changes I made were documented in the text prior to the code.

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much for all the effort. Since I am new to pine, I didnt really understand this. Do you have an idea, how to use the "last" candle before position entry as size for SL and TP? Stuck with that since a few day.. 
All the best!

Comment: That's what your current code does. It calculates a take profit level at the close + 5% and a stop at close - 2%, that close price being the close of the bar where the order is executed, so the one prior to entry. Welcome to Pine! This is the best place to start your journey: 
 https://www.pinecoders.com/

Comment: Thank you! I want to use the "previous" bars (always an engulfing candle) as size. 
If price drops below of that previous low I want it to sell.
If price comes above the previous candle size * 1.25 I want to close the position. Any ideas?

Comment: Added a version 2 to the answer. The stop and target levels are plotted so you can see them during a trade.